# :hover on a shape created using ng-class

Tags: hover, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I just want to hover over a small colored circle created using ng-class.
Can  someone help to find it out? I used the following code. But :hover is not working. Then I tried using ng-mouseover and ng-mouseleave. Then its almost working, i could say. But the text to be displayed upon hovering is blinking.

```js
$scope.hoverIn = function(){
     this.hoverEdit = true;
 };

 $scope.hoverOut = function(){
     this.hoverEdit = false;
 };
```

```css
.Green{
  height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
   background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in statusMap">
 <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td><span ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()" 
       style="margin: 5px 15px 5px 15px" ng-class="
         {'Green':'{{value}}'==='Up','Grey':'{{value}}'==='Down'}"></span>
   <span ng-show="hoverEdit" ><a>{{value}}</a></span></td> 
             </tr>
```

On hovering over this shape,
I want to show up/down status.